# VSCode: Is it possible to run "last" launch configuration with the same parameters? e.g. I don't want to have a test focused to run it

Tags: visual-studio-code

coming from an intellij world, running a test by right click creates a dynamic run configuration. when you view a different file you can just keep running the debug with the same configuration, I notice that with vscode this is not the case, I have to be in the file in order to run the test. Is there a way, plugin or otherwise to replicate intellij's behavior? I've looked but couldn't find anything.

```
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Jest Current File",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
      "args": [
        "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "--config",
        "jest.config.js"
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "disableOptimisticBPs": true,
      "windows": {
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

**Test Explorer Extension**

Using the [Test Explorer UI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hbenl.vscode-test-explorer) and [Jest Test Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rtbenfield.vscode-jest-test-adapter) extensions, you can get at least part way there.

The Test Explorer extension contributes a command called `test-explorer.redebug`.  On the command palette, the description reads: "*Test Explorer: Repeat the last test run in the debugger*".

This command works, with the caveat that "last test run" means last test run *using the Test Explorer extension*.

---

**Debug Configuration**

`launch.json` supports using commands contributed by extensions, as [documented here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_command-variables):

> When a command variable is interpolated, the command is run and the variable is substituted by the command's (string) result.

We can (ab)use this fact to hack together a debug configuration that will launch the command:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Last Test",
  "args": [
    "${command:test-explorer.redebug}",
  ],
}
```

Now you can run a file, suite, or test using the Test Explorer UI, and then debug that same file, suite, or test by pressing F5, regardless of what file is in focus.

---

**Shortcomings**

There are limitations and drawbacks.

- It feels like a hack in the sense that it's less of a debug configuration than it is a (hacked-together) mechanism to simply attach the F5 key to an extension command.
- You lose fine-grained control over the debug configuration, since you're essentially using a configuration donated by an extension, instead of your own.  For example, output goes to the debug console, with no apparent way to send it to the integrated terminal instead.
- "Last run test" isn't aware of tests run outside the Test Explorer UI.  For example, running a "Jest Current File" debug configuration does not update the "last run test".  Neither does using the "Debug" affordance provided by the [`vscode-jest` extension](https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest).

Still, if the primary goal is being able to F5 into a debug session without regard to which file is in focus, this approach may be good enough.